# Developing a RIA with Django - what technology stack?

Tags: python, django

I need to develop a web application with the following requirements:

- Desktop like UI on the client side
- Application deployment
- Scalability (i.e. distributing the service on multiple servers)

What I thought of so far (as I love Python but haven't done much web development yet):

- Django
- Fabric (think I've read somewhere it's suited for this)

What I'm missing is:

- How to create rich clients (probably need some javascript libraries for that)?
- How to distribute the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RIA you need to use some client technology in your templates.

See at [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/).
ExtJs docs have example of Web Desktop app, but this library is not free for commercial project. I like more Dojo, and it is free.

Comment: Can I develop the client as a static web site in the first step and then add dynamic content later?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can do everything in your templates, they are just html pages with some django template tags. Start with simple page, then add some javascript libs for dynamic behaviour, style your page with css...

Comment: May the said static page execute javascript? well, if it's possible, you can pull the content from the server through AJAX and dynamically build the page using javascript tools (Dojo, jQuery, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it may execute javascript.

Comment: Would jQuery also be an option?

Comment: I think, yes. Choice depens on your preferences. Dojo, jQuery, ExtJs are all very mature frameworks. I have already tried several javascript frameworks and my choice is Dojo.

Answer (score 3):

- Rich Internet Application: Javascript to do stuff asynchronously (AJAX). If you want a desktop-like interface on the web, it seems currently [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) is the way to go. It's a language that compiles into Javascript and adapted for rich interfaces.
- Deployment: fabric (I think it's used to deploy Python apps).
- Distribution: you deploy the code to one server.If you need to scale it up, you just need some additional servers (of course if you have specific usages like very high load on a database, you'll also need to add more database servers etc. But you get the idea).

Comment: +1 Coffeescript looks nice... would you suggest learning JS first, or go directly with CoffeeScript? The syntax looks quite Python-like...

Comment: I have myself not picked up CoffeeScript, but it is used by many projects, and yes, the syntax looks familiar to me too :-)

Comment: i like the syntax/feel of coffescript, but i think you will need some experience in plain javascript in order to be able to debug your code. The code that gets executed in the browser still is js. If there is an error you need to be able to understand the executed script with firebug/inspector.

Answer (score 1):

using web browser as your client platform?

Comment: Ok, I'm making sure that you're not referring to Adobe Air or to Titanium App

Comment: Would using Titanium App be an option? Just visited their website and it looked awesome at first glance.

Comment: Web-based app is easier to deploy that titanium app because you have to download the titanium app runtime on the client side and then the app you've created on top of it, whereas web based app are updated from server side. Nonetheless, titanium app has more functionality than web based app (file access, sound, etc.)